# How to design a database that is to change often?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I inherit a project of a program that configures devices via ethernet. Settings are stored in the database. The set of settings is constantly changing as devices are developing so there's a need for a simple schema change (user must be able to perform this operation).

Now, this simplicity is achieved by the **XSD-scheme** (easy readable and editable), and the **data** is stored **as XML**. This approach also satisfies the requirement of the use of various database engines (MS SQL and Oracle are currently supported).

I want to move database structure to the relational model. Are there any solutions which are as easy-to-change as described one while using a relational database?

Comment: A normalized database will work.  The ease of change comes from having the users write data, not change schemas.

Comment: If you have constantly changing/evolving settings then why not have a table of Key/Value pairs then there will be no need to change the database structure.

Comment: It seems to me that your requirements would be better met by a key-value database. Have you looked into that option or has the choice of database already been made for you?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It is. The structure of configuration is very complex, a  key-value ​​pairs are unfortunately not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to move database structure to the relational model.

Why?

Do you want to be able to index/query parts of the configuration, or be able to change just one part of the configuration without touching the rest?

- If no, then just treating the XML as opaque BLOB should be sufficient.
- If yes, then you'll have to tell us more about the actual structure of configuration.<sup>1</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> BTW, some DBMSes can "see inside" the XML, index the elemnts and so on, but that would no longer be DBMS-agnostic.*

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your design problem.
I suggest the following;

1. Use a different database. Relational databases are not the best choice for this kind of data. There are databases with good support for dynamic data. One example of such a database is mongoDB, which uses JSON-style documents.

or
2. Create one (or a small set) of Key/Value table(s). You can support a hierarcical structure by adding a `parent` column that points to the parent key-value pair.

I wouldn't recommend changing a relational db schema on the fly as the result of a user operation. It goes against fundamental design rules for relational database design.